# Nested view not being destroyed when transitioning to parent

Tags: ember.js

I have an ember application with nested routes but I'm having a problem getting a child view destroyed when transitioning back to the parent route.  Probably easiest to look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j32yT/2/ - it starts by displaying a list of "users"; clicking Create leads to a user creation "form" with a Save button.  On save, the action is fired back at the route which transitions back to its parent.

I was hoping that the create view would be destroyed when transitioning away, but it doesn't seem to. Adding in a function to handle the route exit does let me clean up, but it seems a bit messy.  Have I misunderstood how the routing works?

**UPDATE**

By introducing an index route within my users route, I was able to achieve what I wanted - there's a new fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/AsJca/1/ - am I on the right path here?  New to this stuff, so don't yet understand what may constitute best practice!

Answer (score 0):

You have an `outlet` for `Application View` and one for  `UsersView`,

```
<script id="application-template" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script id="users-template" type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each user in controller}}
    {{user.name}}
    {{/each}}    
    <button {{action create_user}}>Create</button>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

When you do :

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('users');
```

the `outlet` of `applicationView` gets filled with `UsersView`, but see that the `Users View` has its own `outlet`.and when you do `router.get('usersController').connectOutlet('createUser');` this outlet is filled with the `create new form`. So it resides along with the create new button that resides along with the outlet in `users-template`.

You can change it to,

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('createUser');
```

if you want to replace it, but again think of what you actually need, you know that.

Comment: The two outlets was intentional - I wanted the current user list displayed whilst a new one was being added.  In the real code rather then the fiddle, the create user view is a jQuery dialog, so it makes sense that the user list remains.  On my first pass of this, I had the /users and /create paths as peers and just the one outlet, and that worked just fine, but isn't really the look I was after